# Broken img tag when using url from another site

Tags: html, image

I was playing with making a custom CheckboxSelectMultiple widget for my form. I added an img tag to the widget with the src pointing to another website that contained the image.

I receive broken images when I display my form. The source page seems correct when I view it:

```
<li><label for="id_display_0"><input type="checkbox" name="display" value="&lt;data" id="id_display_0" /> <img src="www.fakeplace.com/s.jpg"/></label></li>
```

But when I click on the link in the img src, it complains about a 404:

```
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/browse/www.fakeplace.com/s.jpg
```

.
I think it has to do with how static media works, but I am unsure how to work around it (I don't want to store the images on my local machine right now).

Comment: you should prefix the src with http://

Comment: And you should post this as an answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace:

```
<img src="www.fakeplace.com/s.jpg"/>
```

with:

```
<img src="http://www.fakeplace.com/s.jpg"/>
```

Otherwise, to the browser it looks like a [relative URL](http://www.webdevelopersnotes.com/design/relative_and_absolute_urls.php3).

Answer (score 0):

As steve and prashanth said, prefix http://

Also I recommend putting an alt tag, even if it is blank, for accessibility and conformity reasons, eg

`<img src="http://www.fakeplace.com/s.jpg" alt=""/>`